# When recording my telemetry website using JMeter after I have logged in the recorded steps continually increases

Tags: jmeter, telemetry

When recording my telemetry website using JMeter after I have logged in the recorded steps continually increases, what do I do? Should I stop the recording ASAP just to the obtain the landing page or is there a way to deal with this in JMeter?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your website continuously loading data via [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp) requests

1. Execute main call
2. Continuously repeat one call which gets updated telemetry data

Inspect the recorded [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers and if they are the same - you can leave only one and simulate the network footprint using [Loop Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller). The delay between requests can be introduced by suitable [JMeter Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/comprehensive-guide-using-jmeter-timers/)